# Add a custom class name to Wordpress body tag?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to place a directive in my theme's functions.php file which appends a classname to the wordpress body tag. Is there a built-in API method for this?

For example, my body tag code is...

```
<body <?php if(function_exists("body_class") && !is_404()){body_class();} else echo 'class="page default"'?>>
```

And it results in the following being written to the body tag (depending on the context in which the page is presented (page, post, logged-in, etc)

```
<body class="home blog logged-in">
```

Depending on the child theme I'm using at the time, I want it to be...

```
<body class="home blog logged-in mychildthemename">
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question - I just took a peek into the classic theme, and the `<body>` tag is output directly in the `header.php` file. What exactly are you looking for an API method for, to store and fetch the class name(s)?

Comment: Hi pekka, I've added my body tag to the question for better clarification. I'd just like to tap into that body_class() function to add my child theme name to it, so that I can have conditional css in my main theme that only applies when a specific child theme is active.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the `body_class` filter, like so:

```
function my_plugin_body_class($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'foo';
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'my_plugin_body_class');
```

Although, obviously, your theme needs to call the corresponding [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/body_class) function.

Comment: *NB*: make sure that your theme body tag, usually in header.php, calls the function body_class() `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Answer (score 19):

You can also use it directly inside the WP body_class function which will append the string inside body class.

eg.

```
$class="custom-class";
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Answer (score 3):

To add more classes to the filter, just add another line that adds another value in to the array:

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
 
    $classes[] = 'class-name';
    $classes[] = 'class-name-two';
     
    return $classes;
     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to add classes to the body tag while in the Admin area, remember to use the  `admin_body_class` hook instead. Note that it's a filter which works slightly different since it passes a string of classes rather than an array, so your code would look like this:

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'my_admin_body_class');
function my_admin_body_class($classes) {
    return $classes . ' my_class';
}
```

Comment: $classes is an array can't append string to it like that

Comment: @ShubhSheth Sorry, you're wrong. Please note this refers to the `admin_body_class` filter, which differs from the `body_class` filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/

Comment: Got it, but that's still not what the question is asking. The class update is to be done on frontend not admin.

Comment: The question title doesn’t specify that. Seems to me, as long as we qualify the answer as being for the admin area, that it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( !is_front_page() ) {
        $classes[] = 'example';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add class based on your page template note that WP now automatically adds per-template class to body tag.

Answer (score -4):

Simply edit your theme's header.php and change the class there (manually or according to some preset logic rules).