# Have navigation slide down on document load just for the homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to javascript/jquery and was wanting to have a menu animate in when landing on the homepage and have the menu show and not animate for the other pages.

The code below Is what I have been playing with.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (document.location.href.indexOf('localhost:8888') > -1 ) {
   //slide down menu
}
else {
   //static menu
}
});
```

Comment: cant you just make it fade-in when the doc gets ready, and make a seperate function for making it static at reaching certain hight?

Comment: This is not a good approach to design your application. I am guessing you have some sort of master page where you are trying to do this. Instead write a separate function in the homepage to do this. If you need more help please share some details of your application's software design.

Comment: I'm using Wordpress and have the nav html5 element in the header.php file which is being used ascross all pages. Is there a way to add a class if it is homepage to the nav? I'm also new to php/wordpress. By the way why would it not be good to do it this way?

Comment: Not to sure what you mean by making it static at a certain height. I would like the menu to not animate for any pages other than the homepage @DiederikEEn

Answer (score 2):

you can use CSS3 animations to accomplish this

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/aQnAQ/1/)</kbd>

set the `<body>` of the homepage to have class `homepage`

```
<body class="homepage">
    <nav>
        Nav (w/UL+LI nav items)
    </nav>

    <!--...-->
</body>
```

then either create your own animation or use a pre-built set like [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/)

```
.homepage nav {
    -webkit-animation:fadeInDown .5s;
    -moz-animation:fadeInDown .5s;
    animation:fadeInDown .5s;
}
```

**EDIT:**

to add a class to the homepage in wordpress:

combining answers from [Add a custom class name to Wordpress body tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466073/add-a-custom-class-name-to-wordpress-body-tag) and [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) wordpress function

add this to functions.php (disclaimer:I haven't tested this but it should get you 99% of the way there)

```
function my_plugin_body_class($classes) {
    //if (is_home()) {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        $classes[] = 'homepage';
        //return $classes;
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'my_plugin_body_class');
```

Comment: My header.php contains the body element so if add the class homepage to it the animation will still happen on the other page templates because they pull in the header.php file.

Comment: You can add the class 'homepage' only to your Homepage:
`$(document).ready(function(){
if (document.location.href.indexOf('localhost:8888') > -1 ) {
   $(body).addClass('homepage');
}  
});`

Comment: @mdmullinax Thanks for the reply. This kind of worked but the body class spits out a range of other classes which interfere with what I already have in the css. is it possible just to have homepage in the body? so far i have this in the body <body <?php body_class(); ?> > along with the code you supplied.

Comment: I did change is_home to is_front page as I have front-page.php template setup as a static front page

Comment: @alexP the animation still happens on all pages.

Comment: @richard I've adjusted the function slightly, see updated answer.

Comment: Hi @mdmullinax is there a way to remove the classes Wordpress automatically includes to the body tag when using body_class? would just like to have .homepage in the body tag.

Comment: you could use `$classes = array('homepage');` instead of `$classes[] = 'homepage';` but your theme may use those other classes

Comment: Hi @mdmullinax I now have `<body class="homepage group-blog" >` This is fine for me but not sure why group-blog is still in there when other classes have been stripped away.Maybe it's the OCD in me wanting code that is not being used to be taken out. Anyway many thanks for your help and the replies from the other members.