# Wordpress how to modify <body> tag of a page by adding extra html attributes

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

In wordpress is there a way to set the body tag attribute on a Page like this :

```
<body onBlur="window.focus()">
```

WP Block editor does not allow editing the page html, because it is visual editor of course.

I would use this code so I can make a popup window stay always on top.

BTW I solved the problem how to popup the window, just dont know how to make it stay on top

[how to create Popup window](https://myriad.website/create-popup-window/)

If there is other way let me know.

---

thanks @ruvee

Wrote step by step instruction here: [update body tag](https://myriad.website/wpress-html-updating-tag/)

Comment: Do you have access to the filesystem or just the admin?

Comment: i have access to both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a hook you could use called `wp_footer`. You could add extra attributes to your `body` tag using pure/vanilla `javascript` like this:

```php
add_action("wp_footer", "your_theme_adding_extra_attributes");

function your_theme_adding_extra_attributes(){
    ?>
    <script>
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
        body[0].setAttribute("onBlur", "window.focus()"); 
    </script>
<?php }
```

Code goes into the `functions.php` file of your active theme.

This answer has been tested on wordpress `5.8` and works.

[image]

---

##### Running it on a specific page:

Depending on which page you would need to run it on, you could use different conditional statements. For example:

- Only on archive pages:

  - `is_archive()` would be a proper conditional check
- Only on the index of your blog:

  - `is_home()` would be a conditional check.
- Only on front page that may or may not be your blog index:

  - `is_front_page()` would be a conditional check
- etc...

---

##### UPDATE (related to the second request that was not part of the first question)

If you have a page with a slug of `blah` and you want to modify its `body` tag, you could use the following snippet:

```php
# The following code would only get executed on yourwebsite.com/blah

add_action("wp_footer", "your_theme_adding_extra_attributes");

function your_theme_adding_extra_attributes(){
    if(is_page("blah")){ ?>
    <script>
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
        body[0].setAttribute("onBlur", "window.focus()"); 
    </script>
<?php }
}
```

[`is_page`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

---

##### For people who would need to add an extra `class` NOT an extra `attributes`, there is a hook called `body_class` and there are too many answers already on Stackoverflow, such as:

> - [Add a custom class name to Wordpress body tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466147/15040627)
> - [body class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247687/15040627)

Comment: thanks, how can i do it only for specific page, not in general ?

Comment: You would need to check whether you're on a specific page or not. If you tell me which page you're interested in, I'd give you the conditional statement that matches your page name.

Comment: it is page created manually with Pages menu that has permalink /blah ... cant find other identifier

Comment: Updated my answer. The code would only run on `/blah` page!!!

Comment: thanks a ton will try it and post back

Answer (score 1):

You could hook into the body class filter and do a echo for your attribute, not how filters are meant to work but it gets the job done without js.

```php
add_filter('body_class', 'bt_add_attr_to_body');
function bt_add_attr_to_body ($classes) {
    echo 'onBlur="window.focus()"';
    
    return $classes;
}
```

I noticed from your comments that you would also like to limit to specific pages.
Lets say you want to to happen only on front page.
Youll need to add a if condition for front page, like this

```
add_filter('body_class', 'bt_add_attr_to_body');
function bt_add_attr_to_body ($classes) {
    if (is_front_page()) echo 'onBlur="window.focus()"';
    
    return $classes;
}
```

Based on where you want this attribute to appeare, you will need to create the appropriate condition.

Comment: thanks ... seems hacky ... what are filters used for